# openssh preliminary authentication

Tags: linux, ssh

I would like to add a preliminary authentication stage to an openssh server running on linux. Ideally authentication would happen before even getting to the openssh application itself, or at least before handshakes etc. I will use one-time passwords, so it can even be done over plain text connection.

Is there some standard way I could do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with the standard S/KEY implementation in OpenSSH? Gentoo Wiki [makes it very clear how to use it](http://www.gentoo-wiki.info/OpenSSH_skey). Basically you just use `skeyinit` and `skey` commands for creating your one-time passwords.

Comment: Thanks it might be helpful to see how I can implement something similar. I would really prefer to have a preliminary step though, as I want to have somewhat better control over it, not like in the S/Key case when simply forgetting to set "UsePAM no" screws everything up...